# how to get visio like editor in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can i get visio like editor in vb.net. so that end user can create or move controls, like text box,labels & combo box. I need this for reporting purpose where user can place the controls as he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're needing something with that kind of flexibility you might look into [Crystal Reports](http://crystalreports.com/).  It's not really *diagramming* like Visio is, but if you're needing configurable reporting then it might do the trick.

You might also take a look at [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx) if you have a SQL Server backend.

Answer (score -1):

In Office 2007, fire up Visio, File/New/Software&DataBases/Windows XP User Interface.
Best regards.